# Error: "Expected a;a before aprintfa?"

Tags: c, putty

Upon completing the code that will net the solution for the equation **M = E - e sin E**, I came across an error that reads out as this:

***expected â;â before âprintfâ***

It could be one of the statements typed out, but I could be wrong.

Code(in C):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  float e = .1, gme = 398600, re  = 6378;
  float a   = 4.165*re;
  float n   = sqrt(gme/pow(a,3));
  float M   = n*4*3600;
  float E   = M;
  int i;

  printf("0: E is %8.4f\n",E);
  for (i = 1; i<4; i++)
  {
     E = E - e*sin(E)
     printf("%d: E is %8.4f\n",i,E);
  }

  printf("\n FINAL ANSWER: %6.4f deg\n", E*180/3.141592654);  
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: The answers below will help you finding the solution for your current problem. Generally, learning to read error messages will help you finding solutions for many future problems. The error message clearly complains about a missing `; ` before a printf(). Printf is twice in your code. Can you please explain what kept your from making the connection? The error message you quoted has an encoding problem, but I doubt that it is the literal compiler output.

Comment: What does this have to do with `putty`?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon here:

```
 E = E - e*sin(E)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
E = E - e*sin(E)
```

This line has a missing semicolon.